# Should a turn request include candidates for stun?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

There are two very similar questions here, but both haven't been answered:

[rfc5766-turn-server as TURN and STUN for webrtc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508402/rfc5766-turn-server-as-turn-and-stun-for-webrtc-application) question 1. says "with rfc5766-turn-server is enough to act as a TURN and also STUN server or do I also need to run a stun server".

[missing relay candidates from TURN server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709804/missing-relay-candidates-from-turn-server) speak about missing relay candidates, the effect I am seeing when making only a `turn` request.

We have `coturn` configured with `turns` and `use-auth-secret` and use https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ for testing.

- When I make a stun request `stun:hostname:5349` without password I see the `srflx` candidate (my external IP).
- When I make a turn request `turns:hostname:5349[username:password]` I see the `relay` candidate (the TURN server's public address).

This looks good, but do I need to make 2 requests to the same server? Shouldn't `turn` include `stun` and give me `srflx` and `relay` candidates?

- Can I configure `coturn` to return both in a single request?
- Or will the client have to make both requests? Is so, will all browsers do this correctly when using WebRTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have TURN/UDP configured in the client, configuring the same server as a STUN server isn't necessary.

TURN over UDP will return a srflx candidate automatically, you should be able to see that on the trickle-ice test page. If you look at the packets exchanged in Wireshark you'll see both
* a STUN binding request and the binding response containing the public ip as seen by the server in the xor-mapped-address field as well as
* a STUN (TURN) allocate request whose response also contains a xor-mapped-address

TURN over TLS or TURN over TCP won't do that since that would not work with udp hole punching.

Comment: does that mean that in case you do not master the client network topology like firewall security rules (eg: only TLS allowed) and the purpose is to minimize clients ICE requests. It is not recommended to resolve STUN requests on top of a TURN server ? if yes, shall the consequence is a fallback on  the TURN instead of the STUN usage ?